# Formula to count number of people of a certain age range and gender

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column for age and a column for gender. How can I get the number of people with ages between 0-18 and with a gender of "male"?

For example, with the following data, the formula should return "1":

| Name | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rick | 70 | male |
| Morty | 14 | male |
| Summer | 17 | female |
| Beth | 34 | female |
| Jerry | 35 | male |

Comment: It would be great if you provided example data.

Comment: column1 with age and column2 with gender.  need to know how many Male people have between 0 and 18 years. i have something like this to know how many people under 18 exist in list  =count.if('controlo'!D3:D500;"<=18")  @Taosique

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your age data is in column `A:A` and gender in column `B:B`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<=18",B:B,"M")
```

(and I hope all age values are >0). Otherwise:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<=18",A:A,">=0",B:B,"M")
```

Comment: Tried that but i keep getting error, done like this: =contar.se('Controlo Atendimentos'!D:D,"<=18",'Controlo Atendimentos'!D:D,">=0",'Controlo Atendimentos'!E:E,"M")   contar.se is the same as countif

Comment: it gives standard message informing me of formulas procedures like = to assume formula. some age columns fields are enpty can it be causing the error  @Taosique